# sparql to retrieve the value of a min constraint

Tags: sparql, jena

How can I retrieve a min constraint on a class' attribute using sparql? I have `value min 1000 decimal`, and I would like to get 1000

Comment: You need to provide a query that you have written. Basically what you tried and what you expect to get.

Comment: Thanks @Artemis, I didn't know how to do it at all, I know how to select individuals, objects and data properties, ranges and domains, but I didn't figure out how to find constraints on classes and attributes, I suppose that it's possible to get this information but I didn't find how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sparql query I used following Artemis' answer

```
SELECT ?min
WHERE {?s rdfs:subClassOf ?o.
       ?o owl:minQualifiedCardinality ?min. 
       FILTER(?s = :value) }
```

And with jena, I use `getLiteral("min").getFloat();`

Answer (score 1):

In a hypothetical world that you have such a statement:

```
Class: X subClassOf: hasObjectProperty min 1 Y
```

If you write a SPARQL query as:

```
SELECT *
WHERE { 
    ?s rdfs:subClassOf ?o.
}
```

You must extract all the `refs:subClassOf` axioms. However, if you need to precise and know which ones have cardinality restrictions, you need to go further:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix : <http://example.com#>
SELECT *
WHERE { 
    ?s rdfs:subClassOf ?o.
    ?o ?x ?y.
filter(?s = :X)
}
```

Among others, you can see the following result:
[image]

As you can see, there are 2 relevant items, one is `Y` and one is the number presented as a non-negative integer. Therefore, one way to get each item is to put a filter for `?x` in the SPARQL query and get each one one by one out. For example, filter `owl:onClass` will give you `?y`:

```
prefix : <http://example.com#>
SELECT *
WHERE { 
    ?s rdfs:subClassOf ?o.
    ?o owl:onClass ?y.
filter(?s = :X)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you're a life saver, I've learned something new